# How to submit image as part of form after converting from canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

Suppose I convert canvas to image using `.todataURL()` and then I want to submit this image as a part of my form.

How can I do that?

```
var url = document.querySelector('canvas').toDataURL();
```

How can I use the URL to submit this image as a part of my form?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code snippet showing two different ways of submitting the canvas data.

1. The first is using standard input element with a `type=hidden`. I've added that kind of input inside a form tag and I'm updating its value in the method which handles the end of canvas drawing. Your case might be different but just remember to update the hidden input value before form submit.
2. The second way is submitting via ajax. I use the very same hidden input and its value but in your case, you might not want to have an input and get canvas data directly like this:

```
document.querySelector('#canvas-data').toDataURL();
```

and send it like:

```
$.post("https://httpbin.org/post", {
  canvasData: document.querySelector('#canvas-data').toDataURL()
});
```

Here's a working example of both approaches:

```js
// =============
// == Globals ==
// =============
const canvas = document.querySelector('#drawing-area');
const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('#clear-button');
const ajaxButton = document.querySelector('#ajax-button');
const canvasData = document.querySelector('#canvas-data');
const state = {
  mousedown: false
};

// ===================
// == Configuration ==
// ===================
const lineWidth = 5;
const strokeStyle = '#333';

// =====================
// == Event Listeners ==
// =====================
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleWritingStart);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleWritingInProgress);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', handleDrawingEnd);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', handleDrawingEnd);

canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', handleWritingStart);
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', handleWritingInProgress);
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', handleDrawingEnd);

clearButton.addEventListener('click', handleClearButtonClick);

ajaxButton.addEventListener('click', handleAjaxButtonClick);

// ====================
// == Event Handlers ==
// ====================
function handleWritingStart(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const mousePos = getMousePositionOnCanvas(event);
  canvasContext.beginPath();
  canvasContext.moveTo(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
  canvasContext.lineWidth = lineWidth;
  canvasContext.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
  canvasContext.fill();
  state.mousedown = true;
}

function handleWritingInProgress(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (state.mousedown) {
    const mousePos = getMousePositionOnCanvas(event);
    canvasContext.lineTo(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
    canvasContext.stroke();
  }
}

function handleDrawingEnd(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  state.mousedown = false;
  canvasData.value = canvas.toDataURL()
}

function handleClearButtonClick(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  clearCanvas();
}

function handleAjaxButtonClick(event) {
  const posting = $.post("https://httpbin.org/post", {
    canvasData: canvasData.value
  });
  posting.done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}

// ======================
// == Helper Functions ==
// ======================
function getMousePositionOnCanvas(event) {
  const clientX = event.clientX || event.touches[0].clientX;
  const clientY = event.clientY || event.touches[0].clientY;
  const {
    offsetLeft,
    offsetTop
  } = event.target;
  const canvasX = clientX - offsetLeft;
  const canvasY = clientY - offsetTop;
  return {
    x: canvasX,
    y: canvasY
  };
}

function clearCanvas() {
  canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 95vh;
}

.drawing-area {
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 #999;
}

button {
  margin: 2em;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="container">
  <form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
    <canvas id="drawing-area" class="drawing-area" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
    <div class="buttons-container">
      <button id="clear-button" type="button">Clear</button>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <button id="ajax-button" type="button">Submit with ajax</button>
    </div>
    <input id="canvas-data" type="hidden" name="canvas-data" />
  </form>
</div>
```

**Side note:** I've used jQuery for sending async requests but you could [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) too.